# jquery: change hint value in textbox dynamically(after page loaded)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jquery plugin for textbox hints.

Refer to the link below for the hint plugin:
http://remysharp.com/2007/01/25/jquery-tutorial-text-box-hints/

May I know how can I change the hint dynamically? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with the plugin, but you could change it to make this possible: Replace the `title`-variable with `$input.attr('title')` everywhere. This would allow you to dynamically change the `title`-attribute of your `<input/>`.

Comment: this is what i am doing. by changing the title value only. But i still need to change the hint value. May I know why it is not possible? which part made it not possible?